# Call a javascript alert function on our UI from asp .net core 6.0

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I am working a payment API with asp.net core 6.0  and react .

If Payment is success I need to send a alert message on our website ( now the page is https://test.sagepay.com/mpitools/accesscontroler?action=pareq which is opayo UI. After the payment success I need to redirect to out website and send a alert message on our page.)

How do I do this?

Note:

I know how to redirect a page from asp.net core.

`return Redirect($"http://localhost:4200/payment-done/{transactionId}/{result.Status}");`
I did this for redirect to a new separate page with transactionId and Status.

But now I want to redirect the same page which I already use to getting card_Details for payment from user and, I want to show a alert message That is "Your Payment is successfully added"

BUT I don't know how to call a alert function. How can I do that?

Comment: Only JS code on the page can display an alert, which means you need to add something to the URL which is then read by JS code and displayed. You basically add `?alert=Your%20Payment%20is%successfully%20added` to the URL.

Comment: Do you want to pop up the payment success message on the current page after the payment is successful? The pop-up message is complete without re-jumping the page?